# Aurelia json method returning Blob Type

Tags: aurelia

json method is returning a Blob type in aurelia.

JSON.stringify is returning the correct JSON type,

Is this is the correct way to call json method ?

```
import {HttpClient,json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';  

var text= {"tags": 'Hello'};
console.log(json(text)); // shows Blob
console.log(JSON.stringify(text)); // shows as JSON
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/master/src/util.js#L7-L9) of the `json` function is documented with:

> Create a Blob containing JSON-serialized data.
>   Useful for easily creating JSON fetch request bodies.

The fetch API can handle Blob types, but just use the standard `JSON.stringify` if you need it.

Comment: thanks, still getting a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error when calling post.    this.http.fetch('api/server', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({tags:"hello"}),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function () {
      console.log('Success');
    });

Comment: Oh my bad, I though you wanted to use only the `json` function instead of `JSON.stringify` with something else than the `HttpClient`. If you wish to send JSON-data with `HttpClient` you should indeed use the `json` function exported by it. So instead of `... body: JSON.stringify({tags:"hello"}) ...` you want `... body: json({tags:"hello"}) ...`

Comment: There's some unofficial documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/bryanrsmith/14caed2015b9c54e70c3) that you'll find useful

Comment: Thanks, no luck against asp.net web api, still getting Unsupported Media Type error. But the Web API is working fine with fiddler or PostMan.

Comment: I wonder if its because i am using no-cors for a post request ?

Comment: You should leave it at the default value - the default config works fine in the majority of cases

Comment: You are so right, i was looking at 1 year old tutorials, all working fine now ! Thanks !